# Convert MBR to GPT partition format

Tags: convert, gpt

Is there a way I can convert an MBR partition setup to a GPT partitions with out having to destroy all my data?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/mbr2gpt.html  Is what you want.

From the page:
One of the more unusual features of gdisk is its ability to read an MBR partition table or BSD disklabel and convert it to GPT format without damaging the contents of the partitions on the disk.

Comment: I was able to run GDisk from WinPE (booting to Win10 ISO), then followed instructions here to resolve the issue: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/14286.converting-windows-bios-installation-to-uefi.aspx